# SQL to "order by" 2 nvarchar columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have 2 nvarchar columns which I need to order my query by (Column 1 example: TW001_1, Column 2 Example: Test Documentation_2)

How do I order 2 NVARCHAR columns in the same way I would using an integer (order by column1, column2 asc)?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same way I would using an integer"? Do you mean that "abc11" should come before "abc100" in the same way as number 11 comes before 100?

Comment: Hi, yes please.

Comment: Hm, I don't think that's possible. You can either sort as text or as numbers, not a mixture of two. If the format is fairly static, e.g. 3 letter followed by a number, you can break it up into two fields using substring function, and then sort them separately. BTW, do not post answers to your own questions. Edit the question instead to add more detail. You may get banned, they are very strict policing the rules on SO. Read the rules for posting...

Comment: Thanks,what would be the best way to break it up into 2 fields.  Any chance you could give me an example? all of the numbers follow this format AB31000016_1. AB32000017_2 etc

Comment: Don't post more questions as answers, this is not a discussion forum, instead edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the text into text part and the number part and then apply the sorting you want. For example:

```
SELECT column1, LEFT(column1, 2) as textSort, CAST(SUBSTRING(column1, 3, 8) as int) as numberSort1, CAST(RIGHT(column1, 1) as int) as numberSort2
FROM table1 
ORDER BY textSort, numberSort1, numberSort2;
```

This is based on the assumption and the column1 is in the following format AA99999999_9 (i.e., 2 letters, followed by 8 digits, then underscore and a single digit).